# How to prove the roots of $ax^2 + bx + a$ are reciprocals of each other?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-reciprocity

How to prove the roots of $ax^2 + bx + a$ are reciprocals of each other? I tried using quadratic formula to find the two roots but got stuck at the part on how to prove they are reciprocal.

Please offer some help, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Comment: In order to prove that two things are reciprocal, you multiply them and check if that product equals one.

Comment: Unstated assumption: $a\ne0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha\neq 0$ be a root. Then, $a\alpha^2+b\alpha +a=0$. If you divide the equation by $\alpha^2$, you will get

$$\frac{a}{\alpha^2}+\frac{b}{\alpha}+a=0$$

What does the previous equation imply?